# ¿Como consultar los NO leidos con SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Hice un sistema donde la gente puede publicar temas e interactuar con otras personas, lo que necesito es seleccionar con una consulta los temas que el usuario no leyo, las tablas son estas:

temas:

```
Id, categoria, id_autor, titulo, descripcion
```

temas_vistos

```
id_tema, id_usuario, fecha
```

Alguien sabe como se puede hacer esto?. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola buen dia Patricio

la consulta quedaría a si, para que te devuelva los temas que el usuario no vio.

> select * from temas where id not in (select id_tema from temas_vistos);

Saludos.